# Bootstrap type="date" does not support in all browsers

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have used bootstrap framework as for the front end of my websites. There in one input field it consists of date where I have used type='date' and displays the calendar , but type='date' ( displays calendar) only for browser chrome but not in Firefox and internet explorer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Bootstrap. [`date` is plain HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#date-state-(type=date)).

It is new in HTML 5 and, as you have noticed, has [limited browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=date).

You could write or find a JavaScript polyfill to simulate support in other browsers.